# How to use Stomp ACK "client-individual" with ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, stomp

I'd like to implement a setup with an ActiveMQ broker and very basic Stomp clients that only handle exactly one message (request-reply) at a time.

I'm using an embedded ActiveMQ (5.15.1) broker inside a Spring (5.0.0.RELEASE) Boot (1.5.7.RELEASE) + Apache Camel (2.20.0) JMS application, and for the Stomp clients Spring Boot with Apache Camel's Stomp implementation. The "main" application receives HTTP POSTs, determines the respectively responsible queue, and sends the POST body as InOut (`replyTo` option) message via JMS (Apache Camel ActiveMQComponent) to the embedded broker using the `vm://localhost` connector. The Stomp clients connect to the broker via TCP, read requests from a queue, and send the (correlated) responses to the `replyTo` response queue. Eventually after correlation the response is returned in the HTTP response to the caller.

For testing the whole setup, I use SoapUI as test driver and settable "fake" request durations in the Stomp clients (in order to simulate long request processing times).

Basically I want to achieve the following:

- SoapUI load test with 1 thread for 60 seconds, Stomp client with simulated request processing time of 1000 milliseconds: I expect 60 handled requests (average request time a bit more than 1000 ms) with basically no messages residing in the broker
- SoaupUI load test with 2 threads for 60 seconds, Stomp client with simulated request processing time of 1000 milliseconds: Again 60 handled requests **BUT** with average request time of a bit more than 2000 milliseconds and there should always be one message queued in the broker (NOT somewhere in a transport buffer) waiting for the other one to finish
- and so forth...

My first attempt to get the desired behavior was to change the default behavior of the ActiveMQ consumer regarding `prefetchSize` and `dispatchAsync` as described [here](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) right upon Stomp client subscription. However the default auto acknowledgment seems to come in the way here. Since messages are acknowledged right way (not sure when exactly that is) I pretty much never see a message residing inside the broker (checked with Java VisualVM); the messages seem to be acknowledged right upon receiving. And this basically works *against* the `prefetchSize`.

So then I wanted to use client ACK, in fact individual ACK as described in the [STOMP spec](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.1.html#SUBSCRIBE_ack_Header). Apparently the Camel Stomp component does not support that (at least I could not find how). So I extended the Apache Camel Stomp component to send a client ACK **after** the exchange processing. For this I implemented and registered a customized `org.apache.camel.component.stomp.StompEndpoint`. The ACK seems to be working fine and I also get the expected behavior, i.e., there is only exactly **one** message in the Stomp client at a time and since the ACK is only sent after it is processed (and the response sent), any parallel messages reside in the broker until the (individual) ACK.

But unfortunately now, when I test this scenario with a high load, I get deadlocks in `org.apache.activemq.broker.region.PrefetchSubscription`:

```
Found one Java-level deadlock:
=============================
"ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:64896@25201":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x0000000026153878 (object 0x00000006c4dc0d90, a java.lang.Object),
  which is held by "ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-2"
"ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-2":
  waiting for ownable synchronizer 0x00000006c4db37f8, (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync),
  which is held by "ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:64896@25201"

Java stack information for the threads listed above:
===================================================
"ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:64896@25201":
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.PrefetchSubscription.dispatchPending(PrefetchSubscription.java:632)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000006c4dc0d90> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.PrefetchSubscription.acknowledge(PrefetchSubscription.java:394)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion.acknowledge(AbstractRegion.java:528)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.acknowledge(RegionBroker.java:475)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.acknowledge(BrokerFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.acknowledge(BrokerFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransactionBroker.acknowledge(TransactionBroker.java:276)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.acknowledge(BrokerFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processMessageAck(TransportConnection.java:581)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.MessageAck.visit(MessageAck.java:245)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:330)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:194)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:45)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:301)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompTransportFilter.sendToActiveMQ(StompTransportFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.sendToActiveMQ(ProtocolConverter.java:202)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.onStompAck(ProtocolConverter.java:456)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.onStompCommand(ProtocolConverter.java:250)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompTransportFilter.onCommand(StompTransportFilter.java:85)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:233)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
"ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-2":
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c4db37f8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:66)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.dispatch(TransportConnection.java:1486)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processDispatch(TransportConnection.java:971)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.dispatchSync(TransportConnection.java:927)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.PrefetchSubscription.dispatch(PrefetchSubscription.java:742)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.PrefetchSubscription.dispatchPending(PrefetchSubscription.java:664)
    - locked <0x00000006c4dc0da0> (a java.lang.Object)
    - locked <0x00000006c4dc0d90> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.PrefetchSubscription.add(PrefetchSubscription.java:159)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.doActualDispatch(Queue.java:2121)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.doDispatch(Queue.java:2069)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.pageInMessages(Queue.java:2210)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.iterate(Queue.java:1644)
    - locked <0x00000006c4dc21c0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Found 1 deadlock.
```

Interestingly this deadlock does not appear, if I don't use connection pooling in the "main" application, that is for the `vm://localhost` connection to the broker. But this creates a new producer for each message sent to the broker and is extremly slow. Using a `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` with a pooled connection factory drastically speeds things up but leads to the deadlock. The deadlock also appears in the first of the mentioned load tests, where there are no parallel requests.

The (embedded) broker setup:

```
@Bean
public BrokerService embeddedBroker() throws Exception {
    final BrokerService embeddedBroker = new BrokerService();
    embeddedBroker.addConnector("stomp://0.0.0.0:" + this.configuration.getBrokerStompPort());
    return embeddedBroker;
}

@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public PooledConnectionFactory activeMQPooledConnectionFactory() {
    final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
            "vm://localhost?create=false");
    final PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return pooledConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("embeddedBroker")
public ActiveMQComponent embeddedBrokerConnection() {
    final JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration(this.activeMQPooledConnectionFactory());
    final ActiveMQComponent brokerConnection = new ActiveMQComponent();
    brokerConnection.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);
    this.camelContext.addComponent("activemq", brokerConnection);
    return brokerConnection;
}
```

The concrete questions now are:

- Is something wrong with the `vm` connection to the broker, since the deadlock only appears with the connection pooling?
- Could there alternatively be something wrong with the customization of the Camel Stomp component, e.g. could the error be caused by responses on the `replyTo` queue received before/after the ACK or similar (I didn't paste the customization in here, the "question" is already too long)?
- Are there any specifications as to when exactly an Stomp ACK has to be sent with respect to request/response?

Comment: What version of activemq ?

Comment: @TimBish It's 5.15.1, also edited the question to include the versions.

Comment: Same here, the acks are fired on delivery.